# In confluence how can i add a link inside a block code ? or is there an other way?

Tags: hyperlink, codeblocks, confluence

I'm adding a tree of project in a block code to look like in a terminal, and i would like to link each node to their own file's details below.
Can i do that?
Any other advice/solution?

Answer (score 0):

ok got it
--> insert more content
-> Markup
then i pasted my tree's project, in the insert pop up, preceded by ```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).